# How to make atom more like WebStorm IDE?

Tags: atom-editor

So what I love about WebStorm is it can do amazing autocomplete after putting a "." and i love all the code completions and linting. Webstorm is very resource heavy and pretty ugly. With atom I can't figure out how to do this. What plugins can I install or customize to get this to work for my likings?

Comment: I haven't used WebStorm in anger, however Atom's snippets functionality is very powerful: https://github.com/atom/snippets and autocomplete-plus https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus allows you to perform auto-complete of symbols across all open buffers.

Comment: Yeah, but that's really nothing compared to Jetbrains IDEs which does static analysis on the entire project and makes (really, really accurate) predictions regarding which symbol you were about to use.

Comment: Of course. With a text editor you are sacrificing a lot of features for performance. This question was asked a year and a half ago and things have changed a lot. JetBrains has released solid updates towards their line of IDE's making performance a lot better. For Atom though, it seems like the opposite. Performance is getting to be a lot slower on Atom lately and they just announced [Atom IDE](http://blog.atom.io/2017/09/12/announcing-atom-ide.html) which seems like it may worsen performance. To anyone else looking at this question today, try using sublime text or VS Code for performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For JavaScript development, I would recommend [atom-ternjs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs).

> ## atom-ternjs
>
> JavaScript code intelligence for atom with [Tern](https://github.com/ternjs/tern). Adds support for ES5, ES6 (JavaScript 2015), Node.js, jQuery, Angular and more. Extendable via plugins. Uses suggestion provider by [autocomplete-plus](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus).

Set up your project with `Packages` -> `Atom Ternjs` -> `Configure Project`, and your intelligent JavaScript autocompletion is ready to go.

Happy coding!

Comment: I keep getting points from this question and 10 months later I gotta say I still user `atom-ternjs` and it is still wonderful.

Comment: That's great to hear!

Comment: Looks like a server is required? Is there a way to use this on Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

Almost 2 years later and this post is still pretty popular. For people who are interested, Atom has released an extension to their own atom that gives it IDE features called [Atom IDE](https://ide.atom.io/). From the website that I just linked:

> Get smarter context-aware auto-completion, code navigation features such as an outline view, go to definition and find all references. As well as hover-to-reveal information, diagnostics (errors and warnings) and document formatting.

I have been using it daily with my Python, HTML, CSS and JavaScript code and it works really nicely.

In my question i posted nearly 2 years ago, I mentioned how WebStorm is very resource heavy and ugly (so mean of me). Adding Atom IDE to Atom makes it much slower if you are on a slower machine. That being said, it is a good way to get these features on Atom.