# Code Completion / autocomplete Angular / typescript ATOM in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, atom-editor

I would like to know if there is any possibility to get a similar Codecompletion / Autocomplete in Atom like it is Webstorm.

Right now I am trying to get used to typescript and I really like it so far, but what really annoys me is, that I cannot get any Codecompletion in atom working for my HTML files.

That would make my life so much easier....

That is how it looks in Webstorm (trial version)
[image: webstorm screenshot]

The Interface is very simple:

```
interface Person {
     name: string;
     lastName: string;
     birthday: number;
}
```

The Controller looks like that:

```
module myModule {
export interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope {
    person: Person;
}

export class MyCtrl {
    constructor($scope: IMyScope) {
        $scope.person.name = "Lucifer";
    }
}
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

}

It works perfectly fine in *.ts files...
For example in Atom:
[image]

But it does not work in HTML files.
Like here:
[image]

Any hint, configuration issues whatsoever you can tell me would be highly appreciated!
Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378932/2791802)

Comment: You can try this extension for VsCode `@angular/language-service@5.0.0-beta.5 and typescript@2.4.2`

Answer (score 4):

A good autocomplete package in atom is [Autocomplete Plus](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus).

In the documentation, it links to a list of [providers](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/wiki/Autocomplete-Providers), the one you want is for [html](https://atom.io/packages/language-html).

Comment: Great suggestion; however, we're looking for an HTML auto-complete package which supports TypeScript from the corresponding Angular component.

Comment: @Trent - are you using https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript right now?

Comment: Yes, I am using the `atom-typescript` package.